# How to get PID of a process causing an event of a file or folder?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

While using inotif function in C language to watch a directory, is it possible to get the pid of the process causing an event on the watched folder? I have tried searching but did not get any break through.
Or any suggestion. like is there a way using some external function of any other module to get the pid whenever inotif generates an alert. A different module which will compare the event.

Further explaining, inotif will watch the directory for any Create/Modify events. During any events, at the same time we want to identify the process maybe get the PID.

Comment: The process that created the event may not be active at the time it is delivered to your process and may even have exited. The only information preserved is what is in the struct.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have to install any separate kernel modules for that

You might be aware of the `ps` command in linux which lists all processes there along with ps you can `grep` with your filename

```
ps | grep filename
```

Try using the above command in terminal